# iOS 11 beta 2 to iOS 11

Tags: iphone, ios

My iPhone 6S is on iOS 11 beta 2 and when I go to software update in settings it wants me to update to beta 3. How can I update to the stable release of iOS 11?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm recommend you, please back up your data & Restore your iPhone. iTunes will automatically download and install latest iOS stable release.